# How to check a proper file in android phone's memory?

Tags: android-sdcard, android-file

I need a method that downloads a picture and save it in SD card for later use. I got it finally, i just need an operation that checks if the file in already exists or not.
If not, the app will download it. If it is exitsts, my image view will use it.

So my question is just simple:

How to check a file in SD?

If i got this place for example:

```
String imageInSD = "/sdcard/1.png";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
String sdcardState = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
String fileName = "yourfilename" + ".png";
if (sdcardState.contentEquals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
  {
     String destPath = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ File.separator +fileName;
     File output =new File(destPath);

     if(output.exists())
       \\it exists-use Imageview
      else
       \\Download the file accordingly
  }
else
  \\SDCARD not mounted
```

Comment: just like the snippet i need... testing now.

Comment: Just that there is no sdcard or it has not been inserted, if your sure that there is sdcard you can actually remove the if else statements checking that

Comment: String sdcardState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

I need this for sdcardState right ?

Comment: Thanks for the help Ice.
Just one more question, im not familiar with mobile memory...
Is there any phone without sd card ?
I mean if i use this code for my app can i be sure that this will run properly on every device ?.. or the 90% of the devices ?

Comment: There are some phones without sd card slot like Samsung Nexus S. But they are few in number and even in those phones this code will work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9826/discussion-between-desert-ice-and-adam-varhegyi)